# SQL Group By Year, Select MAX(field1), Display Full Date and field1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a simple table with 2 fields: Date, Distance
I want to select the MAX(Distance) for each year
So that is easy to do:

```
SELECT DatePart("yyyy",[FixedDate]) AS y, Max(Distance) as d
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[FixedDate]);
```

But I would also like my output to show the first date that I found a MAX(Distance) -- that is, list the actual FixedDate field too.

So I want:

```
2000, 10, 10/12/2000
2001, 19, 3/8/2001
....
```

There could be more than one date that a MAX(Distance) occurred on in any given group (any given year) but I just want to choose the first one that occurs.

I can't seem to get the GROUP BY to work right!

Thank you for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select
    fixedyr,
    max_distance,
    min(fixedDate) as min_fixedDate
from
    mytable m inner join
    (
      SELECT 
        DatePart("yyyy",[FixedDate]) AS fixedYr, 
        Max(Distance) as max_distance
    FROM 
        mytable
    GROUP BY 
        DatePart("yyyy",[FixedDate])
) mx on
    DatePart("yyyy",m.fixeddate) = mx.fixedYr and
    m.distance = mx.max_distance
group by
    fixedyr,
    max_distance
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bdd0/7)